# How can a cognito user be assigned to a group in iOS app

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have created a cognito user group in AWS console. I am able to create a cognito user from my iOS app and I can see the user record from the AWS console. Now I need to add this user to a group. Is it possible to do this from the app without using AWS console. i.e When a new user is created the user should be added to a group. This should be handled in the iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and manage groups in a user pool from the AWS Management Console, the APIs, and the CLI. As a developer (using AWS credentials), you can create, read, update, delete, and list the groups for a user pool. You can also add users and remove users from groups.

Note: adding users to groups, etc. requires access keys with permissions to Cognito. This is not something that you would provide a new signup.

Comment: Can you give a code snippet or direct me to how I can add a cognito user to a group using AWS iOS sdk. I use the below api to signup a new user.

- (AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse *> *)signUp:(NSString *)username
                                                       password:(NSString *)password
                                                 userAttributes:(nullable NSArray<AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType *> *)userAttributes
                                                 validationData:(nullable NSArray<AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType *> *)validationData;